# tkinter - How to create Entry widgets that can only be filled with integers or decimals?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I want field 1 to fill only integers and field 2 to be float.

Please help me find a solution of the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("410x360")  
label = tk.Label(text='integer')
label.grid(row=1,column=1)
label = tk.Label(text='float')
label.grid(row=2,column=1)

integer = tk.Entry(root)
integer.grid(row=1,column=2)

float_ = tk.Entry(root)
float_.grid(row=2,column=2)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: One way is by adding custom validation to the `Entry` widgets — see [Adding validation to an `Entry` widget](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry-validation.html).

Answer (score 0):

Install this package, it does the job.
[tkvalidate](https://pypi.org/project/tkvalidate/)

then import:

```
import floatvalidate \\for validating float only entry
import intvalidate \\for validating int only entry
```

add these lines under respective Entry:

```
floatvalidate.float_validate(float_, from_=0, to=99)

intvalidate.int_validate(integer, from_=0, to=99)
```

change range (`from` and `to`) as per your need.